# Android - Edit Action Bar Button text

Tags: java, android, xml

I cannot find any way to edit the text of a button that shows on the action bar.

```
res/menu.main.xml
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_data"
    android:title="@string/action_date"
    app:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom"/>
```

And this what and how i'm trying to achive it:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MenuItem b = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.action_data);
    b.setTitle(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy").format(c));
}
```

This is the Button i need to change the title of:
[image]
When i do all this it just crashes! Thanks for your help!

Comment: post your oncreateOptionMenu method

Comment: `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
 return true;
}`

Comment: just tried something similar and it worked fine for me. We'd need a more complete code sample from you with relevant methods like the onCreate, onCreateOptionsMenu, and onOptionsItemSelected methods.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setTitleCondensed, I have just checked the docs and it seems if the title is long and there is not sufficient space the preferred method is to use setTitleCondensed.

Answer (score 0):

call `ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(this.getActivity)`to reload the onCreateOptionMenu for android version greater than 11

```
MenuItem b = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.action_data);
b.setTitle(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy").format(c));
ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(this.getActivity)
```